# Problems with multiline EditBox widget in World of Warcraft AddOn

Tags: lua, world-of-warcraft

When I try to set the width of a multiline EditBox widget, it flickers for a moment, then gets set.

Is there a way to get rid of the flickering? Or, alternatively, is there a workaround?

Comment: You might get a better answer if you can post a code fragment that causes the issue you describe. That will help the experts recommend something to try rather than just saying "works for me"...

Comment: I doubt posting a code fragment in here would help. "MyEditBox:SetWidth(w)" doesn't mean much.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a problem with the way the UI rendering is optimized. Try changing your UIFaster setting as described here: http://www.wowwiki.com/CVar_UIFaster

Comment: I didn't expect to run into any of the UI & Macro Forum celebrities here!  Welcome to SO.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I've usually seen this as a result of multiple calls to `:SetWidth()` occurring in quick succession.  There are two ways this can happen — (a) it's genuinely getting called multiple times, or (b) it's been hooked/replaced with another function which is internally causing multiple calls.  As a quick test, try running the following command (or equivalent) via the WoW chat window while your edit box is visible:

```
/script MyEditBox:SetWidth(100)
```

If the size changes without flicker, you've got scenario A — go over your addon's logic paths and make sure `:SetWidth()` is only being called when appropriate (and only once).  If it *does* flicker, you're probably looking at screnario B (or, of course, the UI issue Cogwheel mentions).  This may be harder to debug, unless you're hooking/replacing `SetWidth` yourself, but a good first step would be to disable all other addons and see if the problem resolves itself.  If not, my first guess would be a library issue (assuming you're using any).